# What created the Crack in Time?

Tags: doctor-who

> *Doctor - "Two points in space and time that should never have touched"*

In "Flesh and Stone", the Doctor realizes the crack in time is the same as the crack on Amy's wall. At the end of the episode, he realizes it's her - Amy.

> *Doctor - "It's you! It's all about you! Everything. It's about you!*
>
> *Doctor - "Amy Pond... Mad, impossible Amy Pond. I don't know why, I have no idea, but quite possibly the single most important thing in the history of the universe is that I get you sorted out right now!*

What I want to know is what are the "two points in space and time", and what have they got to do with Amy?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, I realise this is a bit of a "non answer" but it's worth adding if only to rule it out.

From [Tardis Wiki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Time_field) (emphasis mine)

> The time field was a body of time energy that spilled from cracks in
>   the fabric of time and space. **The cracks were created by the Silence
>   when they blew up the Doctor's TARDIS on 26 June 2010**, as a means of
>   preventing the Doctor from reaching Trenzalore and answering the Time
>   Lords' message which was sent through the very same cracks the Silence
>   created when they blew up the TARDIS. (TV: The Time of the Doctor)

There is no mention of Amy, or that the cracks have anything to do with Amy at all.

Comment: And what a time paradox we have in this very statement.

Comment: @nickson104 It's not a paradox, it's a stable time loop. It would only be a paradox if the Silence's attempts to stop the Doctor from reaching Trenzalore *prevented* the existence of the cracks.

Comment: A stable time loop like that is a "bootstrap paradox" - still a paradox!

Answer (score 7):

> Two points in space and time that should never have touched.

Imagine space-time as a plane. Two points are separated by a vast distance, and yet they are touching somehow. Think of this as being similar to a wormhole.

**These cracks were caused by the explosion of the TARDIS. 
Thus, the explosion led to several points in time and space touch when they shouldn't have been.**

These are linked to Amy because the explosion takes place in Amy's timeline as mentioned in this quote from *Flesh and Stone*.

> **DOCTOR:** The date. The date of the explosion, where the crack begins.
> **RIVER:** And for those of us who can't read the base code of the universe?
> (26 06 2010)
> **DOCTOR:** *Amy's time.*

This linkage exists because the Silents travel back in time led by Madam Kovarian, and cause the TARDIS to explode.

The occurrence of the event in Amy's time along-with his first encounter with the Crack leads him to believe it is all about Amy.

Which in the end comes true(kinda... sorta...) Because the events further are all governed by Amy's personal life(Invasion of the hot Italians, the Pandorica etc).

Comment: Do you mind if I put some of that under spoilers?  That's the climax episode for that season (but I don't recall which season :) ).  For someone not finished with that season, it's a pretty big spoiler.

Answer (score 1):

As revealed in the 2013 Christmas special episode, the cracks are

> openings into a parallel universe into which the Doctor's home world of Gallifrey was transported at the end of the Time War.

Comment: Though accurate, the crack was not *created* by this. The Time Lords were merely using the crack.